# How to reflect the names from one subnet to other

Tags: macos, bonjour

I want to reflect the names from the WiFi network to which my Mac is connected on to the vmware virtual subnet on which my virtual machines connected.

If you are familiar with [avahi-daemon's](http://www.avahi.org) `enable-reflector` parameter; this is exactly what I am looking for in bonjour.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you will need to create a Bonjour proxy to bridge the subnets. See [Using Bonjour Across Subnets](http://www.grouplogic.com/Knowledge/PDFUpload/Info/WanBonjour_1.pdf):

> The Bonjour proxy functionality that is built-in to the `dns-sd` command line program is the simplest solution to set up initially, but it can be difficult to maintain. Important to note is that although the man page for `dns-sd` says it first appeared on Mac OS 10.3 this is not true. It will run on 10.3, but it did not ship with the OS until Mac OS 10.4.

A [summary of three approaches](http://support.grouplogic.com/?p=1502) is available:

> The three ways to provide Bonjour service discovery across subnets or on a wide area network (WAN) are multicast routing, unicast DNS, or a Bonjour proxy for each service on every subnet. Each of these methods has advantages and disadvantages. In most situations, deciding factors will be the upfront effort required to setup the solution and the ongoing maintenance required to support the configuration.